# Prerequisites to measure theoretic statistics

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

I am trying to teach myself statistics at a deep, measure theoretic level. I've started reading some statistics textbooks that teach statistics in this way, but I find that I am confused on background concepts like measure theory. I'm wondering what topics I should learn before tackling statistics in this way. I have familiarity with basic linear algebra (vectors, matrices, etc.) as well as basic pointwise topology. I am also reading through "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin to prepare myself to learn measure theory.

My question is: are there any other concepts/fields I should look into/learn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to learn measure theoretic probability theory, here's what I think should be the idea course of action; depending on how much you know already and wherever you want to stop, truncate it accordingly. I am assuming you have a fair working knowledge of basic probability at the level of say, Feller Vol 1.

First, get a good handle on analysis. Baby Rudin is a good book for this, but depending on your background, it can be intense. If you find it difficult initially like I did, consider moving to an easier, well written book. The one I went to was Terence Tao's Analysis. Once you're done with that, Rudin should be much easier to handle. You can skip the parts on multivariable calculus.

Next, get a good hold of measure theory. Rudin's next book, Real and Complex Analysis, is an option, but you might want to consider books like Analysis by Royden. Some knowledge 
of $L^p$ spaces should be sufficient. An excellent but intense book for this is the text by Folland.

After this, you might want to move on to a proper text on probability. Books by Rick Durrett and Billingsley are the ones I've read, but there are a bunch of other texts in this regard that you might want to look up as well.

After this, there's a bunch of topics you can pick and choose to study (if you wish to). Brownian motion, stochastic calculus (Ito/Strato), martingale theory, and so on. You might not need much of this but even if you don't, it's possible you'll find a lot of it very interesting. And there are of course a ton of free resources available online; if you don't get access to these books themselves, you should be able to get a hold of their contents and look stuff up accordingly. Hope that helps!

Comment: There is a small typo in Brownian motion, and I would say that everyone who is serious about probability should know what martingales are.